# ViewModel communication pattern

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, mvvm

I am making a program that does database navigation with relation tables.

For example you have a person class and a car class, and when adding a new person you need to also add which car they drive. 
So you have a browse button which opens the same window you used for people, and creates another instance of that view model. Keep in mind that my viewmodel is generic, so it works on all types.

What I need is some pattern that communicates between those two viewmodels so that it can, in a way, return a selected car if you know what i mean.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try something and ask for help with it. Don't just sit there begging someone to think for you.

Comment: First of all I wouldn't have asked if I hadn't tried anything.

Second of all, I am asking for a pattern that already exists, so if you consider that to be 'begging someone to think for you' then maybe we shouldn't even be using any existing pattern for anything in programming.

Comment: Lots of people ask without trying anything. Their questions look just like yours. Why should I think you tried anything? You didn't say what you tried, or what the problems were.

Comment: I said what my problems were, I didn't say what I had tried because what I tried failed

Comment: You mean something like a PropertyInjection? I agree with Ed, thats its hard to consult you, not knowing your Apllicationstructure. Codeexamples make it easier for us to imagine, what might help you

Comment: You didn't identify the problems you had *with what you tried*. Showing us *what you tried* would eliminate a lot of the guesswork about what you're trying to accomplish. Sounds like you want a generic `ItemCreator<T>` viewmodel, which creates and initializes an instance of `T`, and you want to know how your other viewmodels can interact with it; is that close? If that's what you want, what exactly do you need help with? "Write it for me" is too broad. "It's crashing on line 173" is answerable only if you show us the code.

Comment: The program is simply too complex to post here, I would have to expain a million things

Comment: However, what I did try is to add other VM as a property of the first and so on, but that is bad because it limits me to only one vm being derived from the first one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is referred to as the Mediator Pattern.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern

In Prism and various MVVM libraries it is sometimes referred to as the "EventAggregator". There are various versions you can implement, but the basic idea is to inject in the mediator and the VMs subscribe or publish to a known event. The event can pass any data you need with it.

This ensures your VMs do not become coupled and allows them to communicate and is scalable as you can just keep adding new events to the event aggregator and VMs can pub/sub as they need to.

Answer (score 1):

I cant comment, so here it goes.

So you have 2 instances of your ViewModel object and you need to know what type each represents to convert stored in ViewModel generic object to that type.

Try store `Type` in ViewModel so you can `Convert.ChangeType(object, Type)` in your ViewModel any object to specific type.

Comment: OP mentioned, viewmodels are generic. Anyway, chageType is one of the worst built in functions of .net and indicate a bad architecture.